# Why Gensim doc2vec give AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to experiment gensim doc2vec, by using following code. As far as  I understand from tutorials, it should work. However it gives **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'.**

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence, Doc2Vec
document = LabeledSentence(words=['some', 'words', 'here'], tags=['SENT_1']) 
model = Doc2Vec(document, size = 100, window = 300, min_count = 10, workers=4)
```

So what did I do wrong? Any help please. Thank you. I am using python 3.5 and gensim 0.12.4

Comment: @gojomo could you help on the answer?

Comment: @bee2502 could you help on the answer?

Comment: `LabeledSentence` got depricated https://medium.com/@gofortargets/doc2vec-word2vec-in-gensim-c9321c780079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input to `gensim.models.doc2vec` should be an **iterator** over the `LabeledSentence` (say a list object). Try:

```
model = Doc2Vec([document], size = 100, window = 1, min_count = 1, workers=1)
```

I have reduced the `window` size, and `min_count` so that they make sense for the given input. Also go through this nice tutorial on [Doc2Vec](http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/), if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for helping. but I got this error. OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long. do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: At which step are you getting this error? Can you post your error trace?

Comment: I think it was below:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 944, in seeded_vector
    once = random.RandomState(uint32(self.hashfxn(seed_string)))

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: Is your input same as the one in the question? Please provide a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes. from gensim.models.doc2vec import LabeledSentence, Doc2Vec
document = LabeledSentence(words=['some', 'words', 'here'], tags=['SENT_1']) 
model = Doc2Vec([document], size = 100, window = 1, min_count = 1, workers=1)

Comment: Alright, I wasn't able to reproduce the error, however, https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/forums/t/11197/gensim-word2vec-cython-on-windows/68017#post68017 - seem to have a solution. Define your own hash function pass that for training; `def hash32(value): return hash(value) & 0xffffffff; model = Doc2Vec([document], size = 100, window = 1, min_count = 1, workers=1, hashfxn=hash32)`