# Doc2Vec input format

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

running gensim Doc2Vec over ubuntu

Doc2Vec rejects my input with the error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'

```
    import gensim from gensim.models  
    import doc2vec as dtv
    from nltk.corpus import brown
    documents = brown.tagged_sents()
    d2vmodel = > dtv.Doc2Vec(documents, size=100, window=1, min_count=1, workers=1)
```

I have tried already from 
[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509957/why-gensim-doc2vec-give-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-words) and many variations with the same result

documents = [brown.tagged_sents()}
adding a hash function

If corpus is a .txt file I *can* utilize

```
    documents=TaggedLineDocument(documents)
```

but that is often not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's `Doc2Vec` requires each document to be in the form of an object with a `words` property that is a list of string tokens, and a `tags` property that is a list of tags. These tags are usually strings, but expert users with large datasets can save a little memory by using plain-ints, starting from 0, instead.

A class `TaggedDocument` is included that is of the right 'shape', and used in most of the Gensim documentation/tutorial examples – but given Python's 'duck typing', any object with `words` and `tags` properties will do.

But a plain list won't.

And if I understand correctly, `brown.tagged_sents()` will return lists of (word, part-of-speech-tag) tuples, which isn't even the kind of list-of-word-tokens that would work as a `words`, and doesn't supply any of the full-document tags that are what `Doc2Vec` needs as keys to the doc-vectors that get trained.

Separately: it is unlikely you'd want to use `min_count=1`. Discarding very-low-frequency words usually makes retained `Word2Vec`/`Doc2Vec` vectors better.

Comment: thanks @gojomo  ; how would a user convert a document from another format to a TaggedDocument if it is not in a .txt file. a link to the current docs would be helpful.

Comment: It depends on where the data is coming from. The tutorial notebook at <https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb> shows in cell 3 a function which, while it reads from a file, constructs `TaggedDocument` instances. You could grab whatever your own `words` and `tags` are and similarly create a list-of-TaggedDocuments.